# Mapbox sum value inside expression

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

In Mapbox how i can sum a value to an expression?

```
"text-field": ["get", "data"],
```

I have try a lot of solution like `["get", "data"] + 2` or `["get", "data" + 2]` but they don't works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a specific expression syntax for mathematical operations: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-math

To work, your example should actually be written something like the following:

```
["+", ["get", "data"], 2]
```

(Addition syntax reference lives [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-+).)

---

⚠️ Disclaimer: I currently work at Mapbox ⚠️